# CMake - set compiler flags conditionally for different toolchains before cmake compiles simple test program

Tags: cmake

In CMake's `CMakeLists.txt`, I would like to set the compiler flags conditionally based on the compiler ID (e.g. clang, gcc) before cmake tries to compile a test program.

The problem I'm having is that the variable `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID` that I use to identify the compiler is not set until the `project()` command is executed. But, since the `project()` command also runs the compiler test, I am not aware of a way to check `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID` and set the compiler flags based on its value before the compiler is tested.

In the example below, is there is a way to leave the test enabled such that `--some-flag-needed-to-make-my-clang-toolchain-work` is used as a compiler flag when the test is run for clang but not for other compilers (e.g. gcc)?

I am aware that I can disable the compiler test with `set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)` as a workaround, but I wanted to ask if there is a way to avoid disabling it in this case.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28.1)

# Doesn't work because "CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID" isn't set until project() is executed.
# if (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Clang")
#  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "--some-flag-needed-to-make-my-clang-toolchain-work")
# endif()

# Workaround
# set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)

# Fails with "The C compiler is not able to compile a simple test program."
# when clang is the compiler, because the clang needs the 
# flag --some-flag-needed-to-make-my-clang-toolchain-work to work.
project(my_project
  VERSION 42
  DESCRIPTION "My project description."
  LANGUAGES C)
```

Another workaround I've found is to require that `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` be set and use that in the conditionals.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28.1)

if( NOT DEFINED CMAKE_C_COMPILER )
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Need to set CMAKE_C_COMPILER.")
endif()

if ( CMAKE_C_COMPILER MATCHES "clang" )
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "--some-flag-needed-to-make-my-clang-toolchain-work")
endif()

project(my_project
  VERSION 42
  DESCRIPTION "My project description."
  LANGUAGES C)
```

Comment: So move the condition below project(). ? There is no question in your post. `I would like to set the compiler flags conditionally based on the compiler ID (e.g. clang, gcc) before cmake tries to compile a test program.` Why? Why not set it below? Is this XY question?  Is there an underlying issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: Since the compiler test is run when `project()` is executed, the compiler test will have failed before the condition is reached.

Comment: Updated post by adding explicit question.

Comment: "--some-flag-needed-to-make-my-clang-toolchain-work" - So you need to write a **toolchain file** for tell CMake about **your toolchain**. In that toolchain file you could specify path to the compiler and flags for make it working. (Probably, for flags you need to set `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT` variable instead of regular `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`.)

Comment: Thank you. I am new to toolchain files. I will make time to read up on that.